# Drawing triangles in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

```
    \newcommand{\length}{4}
    \newcommand{\width}{4}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
       
       %Coordinates for square 
       \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
       \coordinate (A) at (\length,0);
       \coordinate (B) at (0,\width);
       \coordinate (C) at (\length,\width);

       %Drawing square
       \draw (O) -- (A) -- (C) -- (B) -- cycle;

       
       \foreach \x in {0.1,4.1}{
          \foreach \y in {\width-0.1, -0.1}{
             \draw (\x,\y) -- (\x,\y-1.2) -- (\x+0.4,\y-1.2+0.9) -- cycle;
           }
        }
        
        \foreach \x in {0.1,\length + 0.1}{
           \foreach \y in {- 0.1, \width  - 0.1}{
              \draw (\x,\y) -- (\x+1.2,\y) -- (\x+1.2-0.9,\y-0.4) -- cycle;
           }
        }

   \end{tikzpicture}
```

This is the code which i used to draw two similar triangles as shown in figure. But the two triangles overlap(slightly) which should not happen. What can i do for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I post this as an answer as it is too long for a comment.
Your triangles overlap because the third coordinate of each blue triangle is not the third coordinate of the corresponding red triangle.
Then, you have to change the `0.4` into a `0.3`.

Moreover, I took the liberty to clean the code a bit and to suggest a modification as to how to draw the triangles.
Indeed, by drawing them separately, you will end up with a protrusion to the top left of each of your triangle shapes (that is present on the picture in the question).
Then, I propose to first fill the triangle shapes and then to draw the encompassing shape:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

    \newcommand{\length}{4}
    \newcommand{\width}{4}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        % Draw square if coordinates are needed, which is not the case here
%       \draw (0, 0)                coordinate (O)
%               -- ++ (\length, 0)  coordinate (A)
%               -- ++ (0, \width)   coordinate (C)
%               -- ++ (-\length, 0) coordinate (B)
%               -- cycle;

        % Draw square simply
        \draw (0, 0) rectangle (\length, \width);

        \foreach \x in {0, \length}{
            \foreach \y in {\width, 0}{
                % Draw blue triangles 
                \fill[blue] (\x + 0.1, \y - 0.1) -- ++ (0, -1.2) -- ++ (0.3, 0.9) -- cycle;
                % Draw red triangles
                \fill[red] (\x + 0.1, \y - 0.1) -- ++ (1.2, 0) -- ++ (-0.9, -0.3) -- cycle;
                % Draw shape around
                \draw (\x + 0.1, \y - 0.1) -- ++ (1.2, 0) -- ++ (-0.9, -0.3) -- ++ (-0.3, -0.9) -- cycle;
                % Draw line separating the triangles
                \draw (\x + 0.1, \y - 0.1) -- ++ (0.3, -0.3);
            }
        }

   \end{tikzpicture}
   
\end{document}
```

which yields:

[image]